# How can I fix this "Selector invoked ... on a managed object ... that has been GC'ed" from nib with unused custom UITableViewCell inside?

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a sample project in which I am creating a stock table view, which will eventually use a series of custom table view cells.  The nib for the table view contains the view with a custom controller defined (TrackingViewController), which itself contains a table view as a subview.  The nib also contains a custom UITableViewCell which I will one day use within the table. However right now the custom cell is not referenced or used anyplace; it just exists there within the nib.

When the app tries to reference the custom view controller's view (this is, the View property of the TrackingViewController instance) the app crashes with the message "System.Exception: Selector invoked from objective-c on a managed object of type Empty1.SendDataRowCell (0xCFE4900) that has been GC'ed".  I haven't instantiated any instances of the SendDataRowCell class upon which any selector could be invoked, so I don't understand this message.  I haven't passed off a reference to any custom cell object to objective-C, because I've never created one.  I haven't even set a UITableViewSource instance for the table yet.

Here's a screenshot of my nib file in interface builder:
[http://i.imgur.com/wb5zDlp.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLqz7.png)

Here's a gist containing all the code of a sample project in which I was able to consistently repro the issue everytime the app starts.  NB this is not a fully functional app and it is not intended to be; it simply exists to demonstrate the issue.
https://gist.github.com/cscibri/5437899

I am building this project in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 x64, and I am using version 4.0.4 (build 2) of Xamarin Studio, and the monotouch version is 6.2.3.0 (8d98f5e)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a constructor in your SendDataRowCell class that takes an IntPtr:

```
SendDataRowCell (IntPtr handle)
    : base (handle)
{
}
```

This is the constructor that will be used when iOS instantiates SendDataRowCell instances.

Comment: That ctor was put there originally when the file was generated but I must have accidentally deleted at some point.  Thanks for your help!